# poedit 2.0 not working with zend framework 3 not catching $this->translate

Tags: poedit, zend-framework3

the problem is that the application is bot getting the sentences to be translated form the views of the web application that have the keyword translate like the one below :

```
$this->translate('Login');
```

but the ones from the forms and controllers like this _('Login') is getting

i uninstalled Poedit 2.0 and installed back Poedit 1.8 and now its working

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem (Z.F. using the `.phtml` extension deprecated 20 years ago) that will be fixed in 2.0.1 in a few days.

(BTW, might want to consider emailing support when you have an issue with an app instead of posting on SO…)